# How to get last name first inital

Tags: php, strip

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Regex - Return First and Last Name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1661466/regex-return-first-and-last-name)

Hi,

I have the full name of users stored in one field.  How can i get the full first name and last name first initial.  This is what i am using right now:

```
 $first = substr($full_n, 0, strpos($full_n,' '));
```

Comment: Needs more info. How are you planning to handle `Butros Butros Ghali`? (Last 2 words) `Hillary Rodham Clinton`? (Last 2 words) `John Fitzgerald Kennedy` (Last 1 word)? `Karl Theodor Maria Nikolaus Johann Jacob Philipp Franz Joseph Sylvester Freiherr von und zu Guttenberg` (last 2 words; this is a real name!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(not an answer but too big to be a comment)

There is no solution to this problem, you will just have to decide in what way will you mangle peoples names.

There are several decent examples in the answers already, but they will all fail on Pekka's examples in his comment. Some names like `Hillary Rodham Clinton` are often hyphenated `Hillary Rodham-Clinton` and will be less of a problem.

Simpler common examples such as `John von Neumann` or `Phillip de la Cruz` will still fail.

Answer (score 5):

```
list ($first, $last) = explode(' ', $full_n, 2);
echo "$first {$last[0]}.";
```

Will not work with more than two names too, like all the other solutions. You should save all (firstname, middle name, surname, ...) separatly, if you want to do more with it, than just displaying.

Update:

Inspired be Pekka (comments of the question ;))

```
$names = explode(' ', $full_n);
$first = array_shift($names);
$last = array_pop($names);
echo "$first {$last[0]}.";
```

This works for an arbitrary (>= 2) count of names, but will only display the first (complete) and the last (shortened). Something like "Schmidt-Mueller" will look curious  ("S.").

Comment: $last_hyphened = explode('-',$last);
foreach ($last_hyphened as $lnh) {
$last_initials += substr($lnh,1);
}
.... this will allow you to use '$last_initials' regardless of the number of hyphenated names {Schmidt-Mueeler, Rodham-Clinton}

Answer (score 2):

Well, you're *almost* there...

If it's *guaranteed* that your users will have *two* names (just first and last, with no spaces in either), then you could just do this:

```
$full_n = 'Demian Brecht';
$first = substr($full_n, 0, strpos($full_n,' ')+2);  
print_r($first);
```

However, if you're dealing with > 2 names, then you'll have to rethink your logic.

Answer (score 1):

```
$full_n = trim($full_n); // remove extra spaces

$first_name = substr($full_n, 0, strpos($full_n, ' '));
$last_initial = substr($full_n, strrchr($full_n, ' '), 1);

$result = trim($first_name . ' ' . $last_initial);
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a hard time understanding this question.  If you want the full first name and the first initial of the last name.

```
$firstwithlastnameinitial = substr($full_n, 0, strpos($full_n, ' ')) . substr($full_n, strpos($full_n, ' ') + 1, 1);
```

OR

```
list ($fname, $lname) = explode(' ', $full_n, 2);
$lastwithfirstinitial = $fname . substr($lname, 0, 1);
```

If you want the full last name with first initial of the first name:

```
$lastwithfirstinitial = substr($full_n, strpos($full_n, ' ') + 1, strlen($full_n)) . substr($full_n, 0, 1);
```

This should retrieve the last name plus the first initial.  Or something easier to read.

```
list ($fname, $lname) = explode(' ', $full_n, 2);
$lastwithfirstinitial = $lname . substr($fname, 0, 1);
```